# Aggregating daily prediction intervals in time series forecasting

Tags: r, time-series, prediction

I am forecasting revenue for 365 days with their prediction levels for 75, 85 and 95 using the forecast package as shown:

```
ci<-function(model, nsim, xreg, date)
{
  #Using forecast.Arima function to predict forecast with lower and upper bounds
  fcast<-data.frame(forecast.Arima(model,h=365, xreg=xreg, level=c(75, 85, 95)))
  names(fcast)<-c("Date", "Forecast","L95","H95","L85","H85","L75","H75")
  return(fcast)
}
```

I have to present the results aggregated on the monthly level for which I am adding the daily forecasted revenue to monthly, which seems like the right thing to do. However, adding the daily prediction levels to monthly doesn't seems logically correct because the data is not following a standard normal distribution.

Also, I cannot aggregate the data before creating the model as I would lose the daily information of the additional regressors that we have added to improve the forecasting. What could be the most logical and correct way of aggregating the prediction levels in this case?